# Automating inputs into command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

Id greatly appreciate help with a problem I'm having.

I have a temperature sensor connected to a raspberry pi 3B. To use the sensor, the user is required to enter in command prompt the I2C address and polling frequency.  I want to automate these inputs of I2C address and polling time.  This code was provided by the sensor vendor and not written by me (a total python beginner!)

```
while True:
        input = raw_input("Enter command: ")

        if input.upper().startswith("LIST_ADDR"):
            devices = device.list_i2c_devices()
            for i in range(len (devices)):
                print devices[i]

        # address command lets you change which address the Raspberry Pi will poll
        elif input.upper().startswith("ADDRESS"):
            addr = int(string.split(input, ',')[1])
            device.set_i2c_address(addr)
            print("I2C address set to " + str(addr))

        # continuous polling command automatically polls the board
        elif input.upper().startswith("POLL"):
            delaytime = float(string.split(input, ',')[1])

            # check for polling time being too short, change it to the minimum timeout if too short
            if delaytime < AtlasI2C.long_timeout:
                print("Polling time is shorter than timeout, setting polling time to %0.2f" % AtlasI2C.long_timeout)
                delaytime = AtlasI2C.long_timeout

            # get the information of the board you're polling
            info = string.split(device.query("I"), ",")[1]
            print("Polling %s sensor every %0.2f seconds, press ctrl-c to stop polling" % (info, delaytime))
```

This is the command prompt text that I am seeking to automate:

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I am new in Python but I immediately found one of the problems:
Your `if` statements contain `.upper()` instead of `.isupper` so change it.
here:

```
# These are the bits to change, I am sorry if there were any other errors I couldn't point out
if input.isupper().startswith("LIST_ADDR"):
elif input.isupper().startswith("ADDRESS"):
elif input.isupper().startswith("POLL"):
```